# pulling facbook reviews like google s api

Tags: php, facebook, google-api

I have a link that pulls data then styled and displayed on a website like this

```
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=placeid&fields=name,rating,reviews,geometry,opening_hours,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number&key=key goes here';
```

Then converted into html

```
//Once again, we use file_get_contents to GET the URL in question.
$contents = file_get_contents($url);

 //turn the json into php elements.
 $contents = json_decode($contents,true);
```

Then displayed like this.

```
echo '<span class="address2">' . $contents['result']['reviews'][2]['text'] . '</span>';
echo '<br><br><br>';
```

I want to do the same for facebook.

```
   https://graph.facebook.com/page id/ratings?access_token=access token goes here
```

So I went to developer site created app. Went to permissions after selecting page access token and making sure the  pages_read_user_content was there too, however my current url still has the error .

```
    message "(#210) A page access token is required to request this resource."
    type    "OAuthException"
    code    210
    fbtrace_id  "Ao-Rw_y_lX4UQRAf1TTZt_j"
```

What am I doing Wrong? Do I have to register the app first, with app review?? This page says I only need 2 things to access the data

```
  A Page access token from a person who can perform the MODERATE task on the Page.
  The pages_read_user_content permission
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings

Comment: do you own/manage the page in question, and are you 100% sure you are using a page token of that specific page?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow Facebook page access token guide line, [here it is](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens/). But this first Short-lived method have limitation, access token expire time is 1 hour, if need Long-lived (60 days) access token then you have to create Facebook app from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and have to use `app id` & `app secret` in get request (need also short-lived access token). Follow guide line you will better understand.

**My suggestion:**
I will definitely suggest you to use Facebook app (android/ios) access token and private api. This access token haven't any limitation, you will get full permission like app behavior. Access token will generate when you successfully login in FB app.

For getting full permission access token and private api, you have to use network capture windows software (charles proxy/fiddler/mitm proxy/ etc) or android app (root needed: debug proxy, http canary, without root: packet capture). Search on stackoverflow or on google about network traffic capture, you will get a lots of tutorial.

I will update my answer with token codes & private api codes and more instructions later.